# How to change VLC's splash screen

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player, icons, dll, resources

VLC Forums won't accept registrations by now, so I'll just ask it here. How can I replace this icon in the middle

[image].

I'm big on customization, I even successfully replace VLC's icon to much flatter and more modern one because I get tired on the skeumorphic design of it. Except that one, I seem can't find it anywhere on VLC's directory. Tried breaking open using Resource Hacker tools all the dlls, exe, replaced all VLC icon on there, and that splash screen still there.

Those that are familiar with these kinds of issues, and those that are programming and making Win32 apps, can I ask some help

Comment: "skeumorphic?" Had  to look that one up! Showing results for skeuomorphic
 
Skeuomorphism is the design concept of making items represented resemble their real-world counterparts. - https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/skeuomorphism 

Thanks for expanding my vocabulary!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icons are built into the binaries, so not easy to change.
You have two options.

### (1) Disable the Icon

Go to `Tools -> Preferences` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>).

In the bottom-left, under **Show settings**, select `All`.

Go to `Interface -> Main Interfaces -> Qt`, then from these options, uncheck **Display background cone or art**.

### (2) Change Icon by Rebuilding VLC

The code can be found in the VLC git repo here:
http://git.videolan.org/

Look for the **share/icons** folder:
http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=tree

And, you'll find the different variants, including the seasonal icons (Christmas tree VLC).

Replace and re-compile!

Comment: Ah. Okay. What are binaries btw? How different are they on just PNG, BMP resources?

Comment: @IanStevenMancera By binaries he is referring the to the `vlc.exe` file and the `.dll` files.

Comment: @IanStevenMancera, what DavidPostill says is correct (as usual).  If you do not know what binaries are, then the answer is NO, (as of current version of VLC) you cannot change the icon, and you should not try.  Compiling programs from source code is not trivial.

Comment: 3.0.8  Interface -> Main Interfaces -> Qt,  shows no option to  uncheck Display background cone or art.  https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/52672795484_3890258cd4_c.jpg